# Real time file scanning

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Is there a way using C# to get all the files that are accessed in real time? similar to what antiviruses' real time protection does. I guess there most be an API to hook into the kernel or something?

Comment: Q: What do you want to do with this "list of all files that are accessed in real time"?  Q: Is there any chance you can accomplish the same with tools from the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx)?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

[`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) will give you *notifications* of file activity.

An AV program also has to scan and possibly block access prior to the data being returned - they'd do that with a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx). I don't think there's a supported managed equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a list of all the running processes, and then for each process get a list of all the files that are being accessed by that process.

Please check http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Board=UBB1&Number=23978&Searchpage=1&Main=23978&Words=+AUTOMATION_GURU&topic=&Search=true

&

http://hintdesk.com/c-get-all-files-being-accessed-by-a-process-in-64-bits/